# IE doesn't Invoke servlet in iframe

Tags: java, servlets, iframe, pdf.js

I am trying to view PDF in IE using PDF.js(Mozilla) and IE gives different behavior compare to FF.
I debugged and found out that if I put path to another file that invokes servlet there instead of direct url in iframe, IE doesn't invoke servlet.

For example, this works in both IE and FF.

```
<iframe width="900" height="300" src="/abc/efg/pdfservlet" id="pdf_iframe"></iframe>
```

And this is web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>pdfservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.aaa.bbb.PDFServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
```

But this only works in FF not IE. IE just doesn't update PDF content.(The PDFServlet doesn't get invoked.)

```
<iframe width="900" height="300" src="/.../.../viewer.jsp" id="pdf_iframe"></iframe>
```

How do I fix this in IE10/IE11?

Comment: So you are saying IE cached your servlet response and always uses cached version instead of requesting new content? See if disabling/clearing of cache will help.

Comment: Correct. However, FF and Chrome work fine just as expected. So far, I tried adding Expires, cache-control and passing in random number for this issue in IE, but nothing worked so far

Comment: Can you reproduce that without PDF.js involved?